Why I only can boot Fedora with the BIOS set in Legacy mode?
I just made a fresh installation of Fedora 40 in an Acer TravelMate p259-MG laptop but it is only bootable if the BIOS is set in Legacy mode. If it is booted with the UEFI mode the BIOS says there is not bootable device. How can I boot it with UEFI instead?
The installation media was created with rufus with scheme partition set in GPT and target system set in "UEFI (no CSM)" and all the installation process was made with the BIOS set in UEFI mode and Secure Boot disabled. Here are the specs of the laptop:
BIOS system specs
I reinstalled Fedora multiple times checking each time the BIOS was set in UEFI and the Secure boot was disabled. I also installed Kubuntu and Windows to see if it was a problem with Fedora and with Kubuntu was exactly the same but Windows could boot with the BIOS in UEFI. I also upgraded my bios to a newer version to see if that fixed something but it didn't. Just to clarify, I can see the drive (Gigabyte ssd) in boot priority menu when the bios is set in UEFI but the laptop doesn't boot into fedora  (It says no boot device) . However,  I can not see the drive in the boot priority menu when  is in Legacy but I can boot Fedora. Here are some fotos (The toshiba drive is empty):
UEFI boot order menu
UEFI mode not being able to boot fedora
Legacy boot order menu
Legacy mode being able to boot fedora

Do you use an USB stick or an HDD/SSD as installation medium? Have you tried different USB ports? Some times USB ports are not connected to chipset but third party USB controller chip which can prevent boot.

@Robert I used an USB stick and also tried in all the ports, the results were the same :(

Also check the other BIOS settings. I had once a notebook that ignored all USB devices when "fast mode" was enabled (which saved less than 2 seconds on boot).

@Robert Checked, fast boot is also disabled. In the end I think I will use a Legacy/MBR configuration. Thanks for the help ;)
